# Karma - Jasmine : Show line number when test failed

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, gruntjs, karma-runner

Is it possible to print the line number of the expect that failed ?

I'm using grunt to launch karma test (jasmine configuration) of my angularjs application).

Currently, the console log show, for example, "Expected true to equal false." and the "describe" and "it" who it comes from... But I have a lot of expect by "it" asset so it's not easy to find the "wrong" line.

Thanks

Comment: What browsers are the tests running in? And what version of Karma is this?

Comment: I use PhantomJS 1.9.2 and Karma 0.10.2. If I used Chrome, I can see the line but, if possible, I prefer to user PhantomJS in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack traces *should* be available wherever the browser used supports the `.stack` property on its errors. I think this has been available in PhantomJS since about [v1.6](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/54c41ae77a206050c8be57bdc44a60e646b0e385).

It looks like the problem with seeing this in Jasmine is that PhantomJS only creates the stack trace when the error is thrown, and Jasmine doesn't throw errors for failed expectations.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/291) to fix this in Jasmine, but it seems to be closed under the assumption that everything should be better in Jasmine 2.0 which I think is still in release candidate stages.

That leaves three main choices:

1. Use Chrome or another browser where this does work
2. Wait for Jasmine 2.0.0 to be stable, or install one of the release candidates to see if you get the traces
3. Merge the pull request yourself into your own Jasmine, it's only three lines and seems the easiest to me

Comment: Thank you for the response. I use the third solution and it works !

Comment: Sadly 1 and 2 appear not to work. I tried with Jasmine 2.0.2 and chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit) on Ubuntu.